# Using Eigen vectors in Matlab mex files

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, eigen

I am trying to use the Eigen library for a c++ that I want to make into a mex file in Matlab. I broke the code down to its essentials below. I need to make a return vector of which the length corresponds to the number of rows from an input matrix.

With the code below I get the follwing errors on compiling corresponding to the line:

`double y_OUT[nrow] = {};`

- error C2057: expected constant expression-error
- error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

I can't figure out why I cannot allocate the vector of length nrow. 
By uncommenting the specific line and by printing nrow i verified that it actually contains the right number. Does anyone can give any pointers (pun intended)?

```
     void mexFunction(
             int          nlhs,
             mxArray      *plhs[],
             int          nrhs,
             const mxArray *prhs[]
             )
    {



      double *x_IN;
      int nrow,ncols;

      /* Check for proper number of arguments */
      //...

      x_IN = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
      nrow = (int)mxGetM(prhs[0]);
      ncols = (int)mxGetN(prhs[0]);

      double y_OUT[nrow] = {};

      MatrixXd x=Map<MatrixXd>(x_IN,nrow,ncols);
      VectorXd Respons=VectorXd::Zero(nrow);

      Map<VectorXd>(y_OUT,nrow)=Respons.array();
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Have you been able to correct your code? Can you update it to a working version? I'm unable to create a Eigen Matrix from a mex matlab input parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not allocating nothing in there. The line `double y_OUT[nrow] = {};` contains two errors. As described by the error messages.

1. `nrow` is not `constexpr`. It cannot be evaluated at compile time.
2. by the braces initializer you suggest the vector has `0` elements, it does not make sense either.

The proper syntax for dynamic allocation is: `double* y_OUT = new double[nrow];`. I think that is what you wanted. The syntax you used `double y_OUT[nrow]` is for used for static allocation, in other words where the size of array must be known at compile time.

*Sidenotes:* Of course you need to remember to free the memory you reserve. And the problem is totally unrelated to the topic IMO =)

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce @MrOperator convertion to Eigen, can you take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160609/converting-in-and-out-arguments-from-matlab-to-eigen-c-library-objects-types ? Thanks